# How can I post on my Facebook "page" wall with my user account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment on a Facebook page item owned by me, as myself](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/comment-on-a-facebook-page-item-owned-by-me-as-myself)

Whenever I post on my Facebook "page" it posts as the "page" owner posting.

How can I get it to post from my personal account?

For example, my Facebook account is "John Smith", I have set up a page called "Lorem Ipsum". Whenever I post a status on the page, it comes out that "Lorem Ipsum" posted it.

How can I change this so "John Smith" appears?

Comment: Wondered that myself!